# Ajuda com Update SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso aprender como posso atualizar minha tabela.
Tenho a tabela "Pessoa", esta tem a coluna "Descricao". No momento em que foi criada foi adicionado um maxlenght de 100 caracteres, preciso alterar isso para que possa ser adicionado 1000 caracteres.

O detalhe é que eu já tenho 25 clientes, ou seja, foram feitas 25 base de dados, cada uma possui Pessoa>Descricao. Existe alguma forma de eu atualizar todas as base de dados por SQL ou somente uma por vez? Se sim como posso fazer isso?

**Detalhe:** Estou usando o *PostgreSql*

Comment: Você precisa do comando SQL para realizar a alteração da coluna na tabela ou quer um script para rodar o comando em todos os 25 database de uma vez?

Comment: Quero saber como rodar o SQL em todos de uma vez...

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer um script para rodar em 25 instâncias de base de dados "iguais". Você pode criar um procedure e fazer um laço para percorrer todas as suas instâncias e executar o alter table para cada uma. Um SQL que execute em 2 ou mais instâncias não é possível.

Comment: Entendi, nunca usei scripts, você poderia me passar um exemplo de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

O postgres mantêm cada database isolado, sendo assim, se estiver conectado no database `x` você não consegue realizar consultas no database `y`.

Claro que existem recursos para a comunicação entre diferentes databases, como o `postgres_fdw`, por exemplo, mas no seu caso poderia ser utilizado o `psql` através do `shell script`.

```
SENHA_POSTGRES='senha'
USUARIO_POSTGRES='usuario'
LISTA_NOMES_BANCOS='db1 db2 db3'
COMANDO="alter table pessoa alter column descricao type varchar(1000);"

for NOME_BANCO in $LISTA_NOMES_BANCOS ; do
    echo 'Executando consultas no banco '  $NOME_BANCO
    PGPASSWORD=$SENHA_POSTGRES psql -h localhost -d $NOME_BANCO -U $USUARIO_POSTGRES -c "$COMANDO"
done
```

Na variável `LISTA_NOMES_BANCOS` serão definidos os nomes dos databases que serão modificados. No `for` será executado o comando SQL pelo `psql` de maneira dinâmica para cada banco.